# Can't sign back in to Runescape without name change

Tags: runescape

So I just got back to playing on Runescape after many years. I had multiple characters associated with one email. I got back on and could play them. and I had all of my old items and equipment for one of the characters that I was playing on. I was absent for 5 mins and it asked me to re-sign in and it would not let me do that unless I renamed my character. Unfortunately, I cannot get back onto my character that I was playing on before and now I am worried that all of my other characters are now gone.

Are my other characters gone?

Is there anyway to fix this or do I have to give up all of my years worth of playing and start over?

I have found some questions that are supplied by Jagex in their FAQ but none of them seem to fit my specific issue, that I can find.

Comment: Can you clarify which version of Runescape you are talking about? Are you talking about old school, or RS3?

Comment: You should never be _forced_ to change your name... are you sure you were pressing the right buttons...? I know for accounts that were made earlier than November 24 2010, you have to use the accounts name to sign in (that is the display name of your character).  Anything past that time frame uses the email as the username to sign in.

Comment: You also definitely can't have multiple accounts associated with one email address, except perhaps with username+ironman@gmail.com etc

Comment: I played before RS3, but since I did not have the older software downloaded it opened it up in RS3. Yeah I think that I was pressing the right buttons. Was it possible to have multiple characters associated with one account before RS3? Thanks for the information. :)

Comment: I don't remember what the system was like back in the day, but I know that today you need a new email per account.  If you can't seem to get in anymore, perhaps you can try recovering the account [here](https://secure.runescape.com/m=accountappeal/passwordrecovery).  It's quite a process though, and as I said before, depending on the age of the account, you may need to use the characters name as the username or the email address associated with it as the username.

Answer (score 2):

Runescape being a very old game, I've received many emails over the years saying that my account would be flagged as 'Inactive' and in that way my character name would be freed.

I guess maybe that applied to you?

1. Your account is flagged as inactive
2. Your username is taken by somebody else
3. You log back in that account.

Now I don't have any knowledge of how accounts in RS are programmed, but I would guess that when you logged in your account everything was fine, but after a little while some checkup in their backend just realised there were now 2 active accounts with the same character name and this cannot stand. So it prioritized the one that had the 'fresher' character name, and thats why it kicked you back to the login screen asking to rename your character.

From this point, we can take all the guesses in the world, but only one person can actually fix this. RS Support. So contact them, and try to figure out the situation. At best you will just have to rename your character and everything will be fine from there.